# What code should I use? sys.exit() or some other thing I haven't found?

Tags: enthought

I'm a high school student in a class that is using Python 2 on Enthought Canopy Windows Edition. I often get stuck in coding loops, but the only way I can get out is by closing out all forms of open Enthought. Is there any more reliable way to do it? I've been using sys.exit(0), but it doesn't work correctly, and is leaving my coding in a jam. I can't even test it without it getting me stuck. Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is already running, then you can't reliably type a command to stop it, because the prompt won't necessarily be live then.

Often you can use the Run menu's "Interrupt kernel" command, and you should usually be able to use "Restart kernel", though this doesn't work all the time.